# Facebook Register and Login Using Laravel Socialite

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-socialite

I have an error in the process of registration when I was trying to use Laravel Socialite with the Facebook API login system.

The message:

```
Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError
Call to undefined method Laravel\Socialite\Two\FacebookProvider::getId()

C:\xampp\htdocs\socialite\app\Http\Controllers\Auth\SocialiteController.php:36
```

Here is the code on line 36 :

```
$SocialAccount = SocialAccount::where('provider_id', $socialUser->getId())
                            ->where('provider_name', $provider)
                            ->first();
```

Comment: Can you post a code that how $socialUser object is being created in you method?

Answer (score 0):

the first you need to get the User by the code below

```
$socialiteUser = Socialite::driver($provider)->user();
```

then you can call the getId function

```
$socialiteUser->getId()
```